# Dictionary.Count is not working as expected

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop

The following line of code is not working as expected: If there are two dictionary entries it prints "2, 2" instead of "1, 2"

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Student: {studentMap.Count} - Average Score: {average} - Letter Grade: {GetLetterGrade(average)}");
```

It is not listing the dictionary count like this line ↓↓↓ of code above it in the other for-loop.

```
 Console.WriteLine($"Enter test {studentScores.Count + 1 } for student {studentMap.Count + 1 }");



     namespace Program
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string totalStudents = string.Empty;
        while (!IsNumeric(totalStudents))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many students will you be grading?");
            totalStudents = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!IsNumeric(totalStudents))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("Error! Please enter numeric value.");
            }
        }
        int studentCount = Convert.ToInt32(totalStudents);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        string totalScores = string.Empty;
        while (!IsNumeric(totalScores))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("How many test scores will you enter for each student?");
            totalScores = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!IsNumeric(totalScores))
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a numeric value.");
        }
        int scoreCount = Convert.ToInt32(totalScores);

        Dictionary<int, List<int>> studentMap = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

        for (int students = 0; students < studentCount; students++)
        {

            List<int> studentScores = new List<int>();
            for (int scores = 0; scores < scoreCount; scores++)
            {
                string scoreInput = string.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine($"Enter test {studentScores.Count + 1 } for student {studentMap.Count + 1 }");
                scoreInput = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
                int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(scoreInput);
                studentScores.Add(intScore);
            }

            studentMap.Add(students, studentScores);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The test results are as follows:");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        for (int i = 0; i < studentMap.Count; i++)
        {
            List<int> studentScores = studentMap[i];
            double scoreSum = studentScores.Sum();
            double scoreNum = studentScores.Count();
            double average = scoreSum / scoreNum;
            Console.WriteLine($"Student: {studentMap.Count} - Average Score: {average} - Letter Grade: {GetLetterGrade(average)}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static string GetLetterGrade(double average)
    {
        if (average >= 90)
        {
            return "A";
        }

        else if (average >= 80)
        {
            return "B";
        }
        else if (average >= 70)
        {
            return "C";
        }
        else if (average >= 60)
        {
            return "D";
        }
        else
        {
            return "F";
        }

    }
    static double GetAverage(double sum, double count)
    {
        return sum / count;
    }        
static bool IsNumeric(string input)
    {
        int result;
        return int.TryParse(input, out result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where and how are `studentMap`, `studentCount` and `scoreCount` defined?

Comment: I recommend renaming your variables to be more C#-idiomatic. `int students` does not represent a set of students, it is a counter, so it should be named `studentNumber` or `studentIndex` instead, for example. Also the term "map" isn't really used as a suffix in the C# world - if the Dictionary is a mapping between ID numbers and student objects then consider naming it `studentsById`.

Comment: Definition of 'studentMap' would also be nice

Comment: `studentMap.Count` will just print the number of students, which does not change in the last loop. You want to print `i+1` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably misunderstood the terms `Dictionary<>.Count` and `index`. Indexes start at 0 and `Count` property represents the number of items in the dictionary.

So, if you have 1 item in your `Dictionary<>`, it's **index** is **0** and `Dictionary<>.Count` is **1**.